# Context-sensitive grammar for specific language

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-sensitive-grammar

How can I construct a grammar that generates this language?
Construct a grammar that generates L:

```
L = {a^n b^m c^k|k>n, k>m}
```

I believe my productions should go along this lines:

```
S-> ABCC
A-> a|aBC|BC
B-> b|bBC
C-> c|Cc
CB->BC
```

The idea is to start with 2 c and keep always one more c, and then with C->c|Cc ad as much c as i want. 
How can my production for C remember the numbers of m and n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the following: generate a string in which every time you generate a `c`, you either

- don't generate anything else,
- generate an `a` to pair it with,
- generate a `b` to pair it with, or
- generate an `a` and a `b` to pair it with.

This starts off here:

> S → X
>
> X → c | MXc | Xc
>
> M → A | B | AB
>
> Bc → bc
>
> Ab → ab
>
> BA → AB

(Note that this is partially incomplete). Here, X expands out to a series of `c`'s on one side of the string that are paired on the other side of the string with `A`s and `B`s. The productions for `A`s and `B`s are there to ensure that they're reordered into the proper order before being expanded.

One case this doesn't consider is what happens if you have a string of the form a<sup>n</sup>c<sup>n+k</sup>, but that can be fixed as follows:

> S → X | Y
>
> X → c | MXc | Xc
>
> M → A | B | AB
>
> Bc → bc
>
> Ab → ab
>
> BA → AB
>
> Y → aYc | Yc | c

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a brillant idea! I think that you forgot to add the rule Ba->aB! 

And what if i have this string BBBAAAcccc
i can start using the rule BA->AB but then i can occour in situation like this: ABAaBbcccc and there's no rule for transform the B in aBb in a terminal symbol.
 
It this a formally correct case where i simply can NOT generate my string anymore?